# How much progress can a new player make in a tower event?

Tags: ayakashi-ghost-guild

There is a new event starting soon, *Hazy Moon Delight* which is a tower climbing event. Let's say that I start a new account, with the assumptions:

- No in-app purchases or buying premium features in any way
- I manage to do the constant checking needed to maintain my progress as HP refills
- Gameplay time is entirely devoted to tower completion and not spent on story

What is the highest floor that is realistically reachable by a new non-cash player, and the highest level guardians that I can hope to defeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible to complete the entire tower within the event period, though it requires a high amount of activity (beyond just using up HP before it overflows). You need to:

- Keep farming for magatamas with sealstone completions, so that you have a source of 4* mags to level up newly obtained daemons
- Advance through the tower only, using up HP before it overflows (i.e. fills up & you waste time), without trying to investigate in story mode
- Aim to reserve fuse materials so that you can get the 150F daemon to a very high level, as it often has a skill to reduce the defense of 200th floor guardian ghost

Thus, the highest floor reachable would be 200 and highest guardian possible is the 5* top guardian ghost. However, note that the top wandering ghosts have a far higher defense and need much more preparation time before you can attempt them (as a free player).

**Update**: Tower mechanics have changed since this answer was posted, it is no longer possible to complete a tower without HP increasing items (candy, remedy or nectar) - which can be acquired by free players over time, but won't be enough as a new player.